# How do default implementations of traits (particularly collection traits) work?

Tags: scala

Range.map will always return an IndexedSeq and an IndexedSeq uses a Vector as the default implementation, so Range.map will (always?) return a Vector. What mechanism controls how Range.map will return a Vector? What makes a trait have a "default"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern used to provide a default implementation for a trait is via companion object factory method. To illustrate the pattern consider the following

```
trait Container

class TreasureChest extends Container
class BabySling extends Container
class OfficeCubicle extends Container

object Container {
  def apply() = new OfficeCubicle // this decides what is the default implementation
}

Container() // or just sugar for Container.apply()
// res0: OfficeCubicle = OfficeCubicle@7c182b25
```

We see here we decided the default implementation of abstract `Container` is `OfficeCubicle`. But it is a design decision, we could have just as well went with `BabySling` as the default.

The pattern along these lines is used throughout Scala Collections.

Comment: Is this related to the factory trait for scala collections?